# Spatial databases learning resources for newbies?

Tags: spatial-database, references

Would be taking up a course on spatial databases next semester.

Would anybody know a newbie friendly introductory resource?

A vendor neutral one would be preferable.

Comment: What is the audience? Developers? First year students in GIS?

Comment: I am a geomatics engineering student. Specializing in geoinformatics. We develop applications too but we focus mostly on theory right now. At least that's what I was led to believe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [Spatial Databases course](http://www.comp.dit.ie/pbrowne/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005/Spatial%20Databases%20SDEV4005.htm) from School of Computing, Dublin Institute of Technology.
- [Introduction to PostGIS](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-intro/) & [Spatial Database Tips and Tricks Workshop](http://workshops.opengeo.org/postgis-spatialdbtips/) from OpenGeo
- [Introduction to Spatial Databases](http://elogeo.nottingham.ac.uk/xmlui/handle/url/38) slides from Toni Hernández

Comment: I liked PostGIS in Action but I'm accepting this as it fits my needs. 

Do keep the answers coming people :)

Answer (score 11):

take a look at http://www.bostongis.org
they have great "An almost idiot guide ..." for
[PostGIS](http://bostongis.org/?content_name=postgis_tut01#20),
[Microsoft SQL Server spatial](http://bostongis.org/?content_name=sql2008_tut01#181) and
[SpatiaLite](http://bostongis.org/?content_name=spatialite_tut01#195).

that is really a great start.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking more along spatial database theories but those are good resources. :)

Answer (score 7):

I strongly recommend the book "[PostGIS in Action](http://www.manning.com/obe/)" by Regina Obe and Leo Hsu.

They are the same people who run the Boston GIS site mentioned above.

The book goes into a lot of detail about PostGIS but the concepts transfer well to other platforms.

Comment: Looks great. A bit on the pricey sad though. Time to start saving.

Comment: A bit cheaper here: http://www.amazon.com/PostGIS-Action-Regina-Obe/dp/1935182269/

Answer (score 6):

[Beginning Spatial with SQL Server 2008](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1430218290) would definitely be helpful even though it is specific to SQL Server.  For now at least, SQL Server seems to be one of the better platforms for leaning about spatial SQL operations.

SQL Server Express is free and will give you full access to the same spatial capabilities you would get with the Enterprise version.

Comment: I can say the same about PostgreSQL, with the only difference that there is no difference between free and Enterprise version, this because PostgreSQL if free (gratis), if free (Open Source) and at the same time is Enterprise.

Answer (score 3):

For Spatialite, the best resource is the official doc.
The main developers are maintaining a [great cookbook](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.4.0-4/spatialite-cookbook/index.html) and it's oriented general spatial database too. It's really good material for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

See also OSGeo's Searchable Database of Educational Material for courseware: http://www.osgeo.org/educational_content