# How to perform a buffer analysis in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geoprocessing, buffer

Need to Implement Spatial Analysis in Postgresql. Can Any one guide me to accomplish the spatial analysis eg) 2 km buffer for road network layer.

Comment: what sort of spatial analysis?

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT x.* from table road as r , x where ST_Intersects(STBuffer(r.the_geom, 2000), x.the_geom) IS TRUE
```

assuming that you want all colums from table x intersect road+2km buffer area (and used projection uses meters) . You can also use faster ST_DWithIN(r.geom, x.geom, 2000) (see [Postgis Manual](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/reference.html))

I cant guess what kind analysis you want to after that but that should point you into right direction.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create a buffered featured, ST_Buffer will work.  If you are trying to select other features based upon a distance of your road network, you should consider using ST_DWithin, both as @simplexio suggested.

See similar questions that should help you out:

- [When should I use ST_Buffer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14737/when-should-i-use-st-buffer)
- [How to select all points within a circle in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67836/how-to-select-all-points-within-a-circle-in-postgis)
- [PostGIS ST_Buffer Radius Help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17305/postgis-st-buffer-radius-help)

If you are just getting started with PostGIS, I think you would probably benefit by going through the material presented in other questions already on GIS.StackExchange.

- [How do I get started with PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/how-do-i-get-started-with-postgis)
- [Spatial databases learning resources for newbies](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10376/spatial-databases-learning-resources-for-newbies)
- [What are some good introductory books or articles about Open Source GIS for students coming from an ESRI background?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22030/what-are-some-good-introductory-books-or-articles-about-open-source-gis-for-stud)

Additionally, purchasing & reading the book "[PostGIS in Action](http://www.manning.com/obe/)" would be helpful, as well as reading the many helpful tutorials on the publishers blog at http://www.bostongis.com/